# Getting Docker Host IP via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker

I am writing a NodeJS Application in which I am trying to get the docker  host IP from inside the docker container however; the node APIs I am using get only seem to get the docker container IP..

The first method I am using the os API:

```
require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname(), function (err, add, fam) {
  console.log("os.gethostname API reports as: " +add);
})
```

*os.gethostname API reports as: 172.17.0.2*

I also tried

```
getDockerHost = require('get-docker-host');
isInDocker = require('is-in-docker');

checkDocker = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (isInDocker()) {
            getDockerHost((error, result) => {
                if (result) {
                    resolve(result);
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        } else {
            resolve(null);
        }
    });
};

checkDocker().then((addr) => {
    if (addr) {
        console.log("'get-docker-host'API' IP reports as: " + addr);
             console.log("END");
    } else {
        console.log('Not in Docker');
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Could not find Docker host: ' + error);
});
```

*'get-docker-host'API' IP reports as: 172.17.0.1*

When I get the IP of my machine through Bash I get this..

```
sh-3.2# ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
10.106.117.79
```

So node API calls must be getting the docker container IP. Is there a way to get the host IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `host.docker.internal` hostname, which will resolve to the IP of the host machine that is running the container.

Comment: I'm really confused on this. I've logged into the container and see in my /etc/hosts file with an entry of "-e host.docker.internal". I can't seem to echo out the value and it does not resolve. How do I get this from NodeJS? I am using the "os" dependency and then doing "var hostname = os.hostname()". Do I need to map this somehow?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I interpreted your original question correctly, maybe this isn't exactly what you're looking for. But my thought was that rather than getting the host IP, you can simply use `host.docker.internal` in place of the IP wherever you need to communicate with the host, removing the need for any sort of getDockerHost library or function.

Comment: That did it! You can actually ping that on inside of the container and it will resolve to the host IP. Thanks!